# I want to open the first link that appear when i do a search on google

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to get the first link from the html parser, but I'm getting anything(tried to print).
Also when i inspect the page on browser, the links are under class='r'
But when i print the soup.prettify(), and closely analyse then i find there is no class='r', instead class="BNeawe UPmit AP7Wnd".
Please help, thanks in advance!

```
import requests
import sys
import bs4
import webbrowser


def open_web(query):
    res = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q=' + query)
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    link_elements = soup.select('.r a')
    link_to_open = min(1, len(link_elements))
    for i in range(link_to_open):
        webbrowser.open('https://google.com' + link_elements[i].get('href'))


open_web('youtube')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that google serves different HTML when you don't specify `User-Agent` in headers. To add `User-Agent` to your request, put it in the `headers=` attribute:

```
import requests
import bs4

def open_web(query):
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'}

    res = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q=' + query, headers=headers)
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    link_elements = soup.select('.r a')
    print(link_elements)

open_web('youtube')
```

Prints:

```
[<a href="https://www.youtube.com/?gl=EE&amp;hl=et" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AOvVaw2lWnw7oOhIzXdoFGYhvwv_','','2ahUKEwjove3h7onkAhXmkYsKHbWPAUYQFjAAegQIBhAC','','',event)"><h3 class="LC20lb"> 

... and so on.
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. But, can you please tell how to know what values should i assign to my header?

Comment: @TarunSharma For getting the right HTML from Google it's enough to specify `User-Agent` in the header.

Answer (score 0):

You received a completely different HTML with different elements and selectors thus the output is empty. The reason why Google blocks your request is because default `requests` `user-agent` is [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) and Google understands it and blocks it. [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

`User-agent` let identifies the browser, its version number, and its host operating system that representing a person (browser) in a Web context that lets servers and network peers identify if it's a bot or not.

Sometimes you *can* receive a different HTML, with different selectors.

---

You can pass URL params as a `dict()` which is more readable and requests do everything for you automatically (same goes for adding `user-agent` into `headers`):

```py
params = {
  "q": "My query goes here"
}

requests.get("YOUR_URL", params=params)
```

If you want to get the very first link then use `select_one()` instead.

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "My query goes here"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

link = soup.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
    print(link)

# https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/entering-queries.html
```

Alternatively, you can do the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you only need to extract the data you want from JSON string rather than figuring out how to extract, maintain or bypass blocks from Google.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "My query goes here",
    "hl": "en",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

# [0] means first index of search results
link = results['organic_results'][0]['link']

# https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/entering-queries.html
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.